# Why doesn't my hosts file redirect anymore?

Tags: linux, macos, dns, ip, hosts

I'm Mac OSX and I've previously edited my hosts file multiple times and it always worked. But all of a sudden I now don't get the results anymore that I want.

The contents of `/etc/hosts` are currently this:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

www.google.nl   www.example.com
```

but if I go to `www.example.com`, I still get the example.com website instead of google. I restarted the browser and the whole laptop, but nothing changes.

Does anybody know how it could be that this doesn't work anymore? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `/etc/hosts` file is

`IP[tab]DOMAIN[tab]ALIAS1[tab]ALIAS2...`

If you'd like www.example.com to redirect you to www.google.nl you will have to resolve www.google.nl, take that IP and insert it into your /etc/hosts.

Comment: My Bad. I thought it would work with domains to domains as well. Thanks!